# Trap signals both in script and subshells

Tags: shell, subshell, bash-trap

I know there's a lot of questions similar to mine, but I didn't found any about trapping signals sent when a subshell is taking place on the terminal.  Let me explain:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

trap 'echo "exiting.."; exit 0;' INT

var1=$(echo "ab\nab" | fzf)
var2=$(echo "cd\ncd" | fzf)
```

fzf is a tool to display a selector of items of a list, so when the program reaches var1 a
pretty selector covers my terminal screen prompting ab in one line and ab in the second, with the arrow keys I select the desired one and the result gets printed. Looks a lot like dmenu using this way.

The problem is that Ctrl-C doesn't get trapped by the script when fzf is prompting those lines. Instead, Ctrl-C kills fzf but the script keeps running.
So the question here is more about how to propagate this signal to the parent process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to propagate the particular signal from child to parent.
However, exit code is [130](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) if the program is terminated by Ctrl-C in many cases. `fzf` follows it also.
Checking exit status and sending signal to own process is one of the workaround.

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo "exiting.."; exit 0;' INT

var1=$(echo "ab\nab" | fzf)
[ $? -eq 130 ] && kill -INT $$
var2=$(echo "cd\ncd" | fzf)
[ $? -eq 130 ] && kill -INT $$
```

However, it is not common way.
If it needs to do something when terminated with any errors, using `set -e` and trapping `EXIT` or other signals is general way.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
trap 'echo "exiting.."; exit 0;' EXIT

var1=$(echo "ab\nab" | fzf)
var2=$(echo "cd\ncd" | fzf)
```

Comment: I was about to answer my own question with `set -e` solution, and research on how to trap `set -e` signal for treatment. Don't need it anymore.. Thank you!!